# Linq search query using ||

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I get this to work ok:

```
var results = db.GetProducts().Where(p => p.ProductName.Equals(searchQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

When I use the || comparision to get my new query as:

```
var results = db.GetProducts().Where(p => p.ProductName.Equals(searchQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) || db.GetProducts().Where(p => p.ProductId.ToString().Equals(searchQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

I end up with:

```
    Error   1   Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Uppgift_1.Models.MyProduct>' and 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Uppgift_1.Models.MyProduct>'    C:\Home\Programming
\cSharp\projects\MVC_projects\Uppgift_1\Uppgift_1\Controllers\ProductController.cs
    23  27  Uppgift_1
```

How can I do if I want to include both statements in the search query ?

Comment: Just read error text. You apply || to two sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put both conditions in the same `Where`.

```
var results = db.GetProducts()
                .Where(p => p.ProductName
                             .Equals(searchQuery, 
                                     StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                            p.ProductId.ToString()
                             .Equals(searchQuery,
                                     StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var results = db.GetProducts()
    .Where(p => p.ProductName.Equals(searchQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    || p.ProductId.ToString().Equals(searchQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```